# Explicit operator overload + inheritance

Tags: c#, casting, polymorphism, operator-overloading

I have been thinking about a way solve a problem I have and I'm not sure whether it will work or not.

Say we have a base class called A and 3 subclass B,C and D.

```
        A
        ^
-----------------
|       |       |
B       C       D
```

Also we have three classes  X, Y and Z.

On my system objects type B,C,D are passed as type A and usually I have to convert the Objects of type B,C,D to either objects X,Y or Z (That's not a cast, I manually convert them since they are totally different).

Therefore, to convert an Object type A to a type X, Y or Z I need to check the subtype first and then initialize a X, Y or Z Object with the result of some operations about the A Object depending on the subtype.

I thought about overloading an explicit cast operation from A to X, Y or Z just doing the same process I was doing when I converted them, but then I thought... Would it be possible to use polimorfism and overload the cast from B,C and D in some way that when I add a new subtype of A I do not need to change the cast code of A?(Just add the explicit cast overload to the new subtype)

I hope I have explained myself properly sorry if there is something confusing.

NOTE: I will add a cast overload for X,Y,Z

Comment: So, you have `A`, but you know it's actually `B`, so you convert it to `X`. Is that right?

Comment: No, I don't. I just know that is a subtype of A and I want to convert it to X. (And to Y and Z on other situations)

Comment: I want something like:  A mya = new *Subtype of A*; X myx = (X) mya;

Comment: Then how do you work with the result of the conversion, if you don't know what it is? Or do `X`, `Y` and `Z` implement the same interface (or inherit from the same base class)?

Comment: I will work with the X and what I need is pass from any subtype of A to X. In another class and another method, instead of pass to X I pass to Y but to do totally diferent things

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I thought you want to convert `B` to `X`, C` to `Y` and `D` to `Z`. But that's not what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your cast operator for type `A` call a virtual (or abstract?) instance method of your `A` instance and override that for each subclass of `A`. `X`, `Y` and `Z` should derive from a mutual base class for this solution, though, so the cast operator can have that base class as a result type.

```
public abstract class A
{
    protected abstract W ConvertToW();

    public static explicit operator W(A a)
    {
        return a.ConvertToW();
    }
}
```

In this example, `W` is a base class of `X`, `Y` and `Z`.

Comment: can I declare a method virtual and static (Because I think I must declare the operator overload as static) :S

Comment: @MarioA.CorcheroJiménez You can't have method that is both `virtual` and `static`, that doesn't make sense. And yes, operators have to be `static`.

Comment: @MarioA.CorcheroJiménez: No, you cannot declare a method virtual and static, but you can declare a static operator that calls a virtual method. See my updated answer for some minimal example code.

Comment: @svick: The CLI doesn't support it. That doesn't mean the idea wouldn't make any sense; there are well some OOP languages that support virtual static members.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper `virtual` means that the runtime type of an instance decides what code runs. But with `static` methods, there is no instance. So I do think it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @svick: Delphi supports it, for example. It allows you to have variables of a class type (similar to .NET's `Type` type, but it can be restricted to a certain base type), and you can access static members on those variables. Depending on the actual type stored in the variable at runtime, an overridden version of the static member may be called.

Comment: Thanks, although others answers are right that's what I was looking for :)

Comment: "user-defined conversions to or from a derived class are not allowed"

Comment: @MarioA.CorcheroJiménez: How and when are you getting that error? `A a = new B(); W w = (W)a; B b = new B(); w = (W)b; Console.WriteLine(w.GetType());` works fine for me.

Comment: Myfault, the problem is that actually, X, but not Y and Z is a subtype of A therefore is not aceptable to overload the casting on that situation for X... shit

Comment: @MarioA.CorcheroJiménez: If I understood the situation correctly, `B`, `C` and `D` should be subtypes of `A`, and `X`, `Y` and `Z` should be subtypes of `W`. Among `A` and `W`, none is a subtype of the other.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that X, Y and Z derive from a common type T, declare an abstract conversion method in A

```
public abstract class A
{
    public abstract T Convert();
}
```

and override it in B to return an X, in C to return a Y and in D to return a Z. This way each type is responsible to return its own converted type and there is no change to make in A when a new type is added.

Answer (score 2):

```
abstract class A
{
    public abstract object Convert();
}
class B : A
{
    public override object Convert()
    {
        return ConvertToX();
    }
    public X ConvertToX()
    {
        return new X();
    }
}
void SomeMethod()
{
    A o = new B();
    var result = (X)o.Convert();
}
```

This lets you have a strongly-typed result when you know that class is `B`, (through `ConvertToX`, since `X Convert()` can't override `object Convert()`) and an `object` when you only know it's an `A`.  Since explicit conversions can only happen based on the static type of the variable you're using, there's not really a good way to do this using casting, like you asked.

---

(@svick pointed out a major flaw in my previous code, which is below, which is that you can't easily do anything with it if you only know the object is an `A`, not an `A<T>`.  I'll keep it here in case you have any use for it:)

```
interface IConvertible<out T>
{
    T Convert();
}
abstract class A
{
}
abstract class A<T> : A, IConvertible<T>
{
    public abstract T Convert();
    public static explicit operator T(A<T> a)
    {
        return a.Convert();
    }
}
class B : A<X>
{
    public override X Convert()
    {
        // TODO implement this
    }
}
```

And if you have a type that can be converted to multiple types, you could do:

```
class B : A<X>, IConvertible<Y>
{
    public override X Convert()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    Y IConvertible<Y>.Convert()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Or:

```
class B : A, IConvertible<X>, IConvertible<Y>
{
    X IConvertible<X>.Convert()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    Y IConvertible<Y>.Convert()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: And how would you use that if you have a variable of type `A`?